# Larger YouTube videos bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, firefox, youtube, bookmarklet

Read a piece on how to "[Keep YouTube Videos Large with this Bookmarklet](http://lifehacker.com/batch-forwarding-large-youtube-videos-and-big-jobs-1547592437)"

**And I used this script:**

```
javascript:void(document.<wbr>cookie="wide=1;expires=Wed, 12 Feb 2015 12:23:45 GMT")
```

**to create a bookmarklet:**

[image: So the bookmarklet looks like this:]

I got to YouTube, pick a random video and click the bookmarklet in the bookmarks toolbar but it has no effect on the video player.

Firefox version 27.0.1

Does this even work? And if it does, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code has an error. Must remove the `<wbr>`.

Also, this is probably better:

```
document.cookie='wide=1;expires='+(new Date((new Date()).getTime()+365*24*60*60*1000)).toUTCString()+'; path=/; domain=.youtube.com'
```